# Stack View's subviews are not updating correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton, uikit, viewcontroller

I am developing a quiz app and have a stackview that consists of an array of unbuttons. The amount of buttons in the array depends on an `Int` value produced from the function `presentQuestion` that is determined by how many answer choices is associated with a question (for example: one question could have 3 possible choices, another 2 or 5 and so on).

When `QuizController` is initially loaded into the view hierarchy, the amount of buttons displayed is correct. However once the user selects the correct button, another view controller is presented and then the user is taking back to `QuizController` and the the view is loaded again the wrong amount of buttons are displayed.

Here is what the initial QuizController looks like (correct amount of buttons displayed):

[image]

Here is what QuizController looks like once the second question is presented (extra buttons are displayed and answer choices from the previous presented question are shown):

[image]

Here is the code for QuizController:

```
class QuizController: UIViewController {

    var questionChoices = [UIButton]()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        choicesView.addSubview(buttonStack)

        // Function call that presents question
        let answer = questionData.presentQuestion(view: choicesView, label: questionLabel, buttons: questionChoices)

        var correctAnswer = answer.answerNum
        var answerChoices = answer.options
        var bCount = answer.buttonCount

        // Int variables for customizing buttons
        var x = 0
        var y = 1
        var z = 1

        for _ in (1...bCount) {

            questionChoices.append(UIButton())
            questionChoices[x].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            questionChoices[x].layer.cornerRadius = 17.5
            questionChoices[x].titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 18)
            questionChoices[x].tag = y

            if questionChoices[x].tag == correctAnswer {
                questionChoices[x].setTitle(answerChoices[0], for: .normal)
                print("The right answer is \(questionChoices[x].titleLabel?.text) | button: \(questionChoices[x].tag)")
            }

            else {
                questionChoices[x].setTitle(answerChoices[z], for: .normal)
                z += 1
            }

            print((questionChoices[x].titleLabel?.text)!)

            x += 1
            y += 1
        }

        for choice in questionChoices {

            buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(choice)
            choice.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            choice.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            choice.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.choicesView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1275).isActive = true
            choice.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkAnswer), for: .touchUpInside)

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you probably need to clear your `questionChoices` array.

Comment: Where would you suggest I clear the array?

Comment: What are you doing in checkAnswer?? I think you will have to clear `questionChoices`  array in your checkAnswer after you have verified that its correct answer. After that view, you will have to reload your view(Make sure you reload with new data.)

Comment: When you are coming back from the newly presented ViewController, viewWillAppear() will get call again. Just call `questionChoices.removeAll()` after `var bCount = answer.buttonCount`. And also remove all ArrangedSubViews from buttonStack before for loop.